# Show several progressbars and update them at once without printing extra lines

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, tqdm

**Python version**: 3.6

**OS**: Windows 10

I want to parallel a function execution with several parameters. For that reason I use `multiprocessing` object `Pool` with a `map` method. Since each of the function call lasts for several hours, I want to track my progress by using `tqdm` progressbars.

For that reason I tried the following code:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

from tqdm import tqdm


def some_func(date1):
    for i in range(1000000):
        pass


def load_data(date1, n_process):
    dLength = 100
    progressbar = tqdm(range(0, dLength), position=n_process)
    for i in range(dLength):
        some_func(date1)
        progressbar.update(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    d1 = date(2018, 5, 22)
    d2 = date(2018, 5, 26)

    delta = d2 - d1

    dates_range = []

    for i in range(delta.days + 1):
        date1 = d1 + timedelta(i)
        dates_range.append(date1)
    n_processes = 5

    with Pool(n_processes) as p:

        p.starmap(load_data, zip(dates_range, range(n_processes)))
```

The problem is that progressbars start to repeat and are inconvenient to track:

0%|          | 0/101373 [00:00

0%|          | 0/101373 [00:05

0%|          | 1/101373 [00:09<128:35:56,  4.57s/it]
  0%|          | 0/217102 [00:01

0%|          | 0/214016 [00:00

0%|          | 3/101373 [00:11<97:28:47,  3.46s/it]

0%|          | 0/214016 [00:01

0%|          | 6/101373 [00:12<72:00:37,  2.56s/it]
  0%|          | 1/217102 [00:03<81:07:30,  1.35s/it]

0%|          | 1/214016 [00:02<66:16:01,  1.11s/it]
  0%|          | 3/217102 [00:04<66:47:19,  1.11s/it]

How can I transform this text to smth like:

0%|          | 0/101373 [00:00

0%|          | 0/101373 [00:05

0%|          | 0/217102 [00:00

0%|          | 0/101373 [00:09<128:35:56,  4.57s/it]

0%|          | 0/217102 [00:01

then, in the same lines:

0%|          | 1/101373 [00:00

0%|          | 5/101373 [00:05

0%|          | 20/217102 [00:00

0%|          | 15/101373 [00:09<128:35:56,  4.57s/it]

0%|          | 30/217102 [00:01

and so on...?

Comment: You should provide a working example. I am not used to tqdm but maybe this `progressbar = tqdm(range(0, dLength), position=n_process)
     for i in range(dLength):` should be just `for i in tqdm(range(dLength):`

Comment: `tqdm` seems to have a nice demo at https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#nested-progress-bars …  why not adapt that?

Comment: You need the main thread to update the progress bars (that is to draw them on the terminal) and not the workers. If you don't you have both tell each worker where on the screen to draw and serialize their output with locks.

Comment: @T.Lucas, updated the example. Unfortunately, your example did not help.

Comment: @SamMason, I read the documentation before using. The example in nested progress bars, including using `freeze_support()` did not work (I just copied code form this page and executed).

Comment: @DanD., as far as I understand, `if __name__ == '__main__':` makes my main thread a daemon, so could you please provide an example of code where I can see the difference between what I had made and you proposed?

Comment: It does not do that. It only prevents that code from running when the file is imported as a module rather than executed as a script. It is important on Windows as the file is imported rather than being inherited by the workers as it is on platforms having fork(2).

Comment: Attempting to print on the terminal with more than one process at a time will result in garbled output. Either one moves the output from the workers to the main process or one has to use a lock that each of the processes acquire before printing. Or one creates a pty for each of the workers and then merges their output in the same way that a terminal multiplexer does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187632/discussion-between-alex-and-dan-d).

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with you. I figure out to display progress bar for each process as well as a progress bar indicating the whole progress with an extra process maintaining all the progress bars. `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()` is used for communications between processes (to create, update and close the progress bar). Here is my test code.

```py
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm
def maintain_pbar(queue, num_of_tasks):
    """
    {
        "id": taskid,
        "cmd": "create", "update", "terminate" or "finish"
        "data": int, parameters for cmd
        "message": string for updating the description of tqdm progress bar
    }
    """
    pbars = dict()
    overall_pbar = tqdm(total=num_of_tasks, ncols=80, desc="Total progress")
    while True:
        message = queue.get(True)
        if message["cmd"] == "create":
            pbars[str(message["id"])] = tqdm(total=message["data"],
                                             ncols=80,
                                             desc="Task #" + str(message["id"]) + message["message"])
        elif message["cmd"] == "update":
            pbars[str(message["id"])].update(message["data"])
        elif message["cmd"] == "terminate":
            pbars[str(message["id"])].close()
            overall_pbar.update()
        elif message["cmd"] == "finish":
            overall_pbar.close()
            break

def progresser(params):
    n = params[0]
    queue = params[1]
    interval = 0.01 / (n + 2)
    total = 5000
    queue.put({"id": n, "cmd": "create", "data": total, "message": ""})
    for _ in range(total):
        sleep(interval)
        queue.put({"id": n, "cmd":"update", "data": 1, "message":""})
    queue.put({"id": n, "cmd": "terminate", "data": 1, "message": ""})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    l = [(i, queue) for i in range(20)]
    pool.apply_async(maintain_pbar, (queue, len(l)))
    pool.map(progresser, l)
    queue.put({"cmd": "finish"})
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had the same problem of progress bars jumping around. This solved the problem. Very nice solution. Thanks!